# Python2.7 Generate sql query with format() and buffer object from sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, binary, format

I try to build an sql query string with .format() and binary content (injections are no problem). The minimal example needs an example image in the same path.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sqlite3 as lite
import sys

try:
    con = lite.connect(':memory:')

    cur = con.cursor()
    binary = lite.Binary(open("woman.jpg", "rb").read())

    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE 'Images' ('Data' BLOB)") 
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Images(Data) VALUES (?)", (binary,) )

    query = "INSERT INTO Images(Data) VALUES ({0})".format(binary)
    cur.execute(query) # <- doesn't work obviously

    con.commit()    

except lite.Error, e:

    if con:
        con.rollback()

    print "Error %s:" % e.args[0]
    sys.exit(1)

finally:

    if con:
        con.close()
```

Just like the insert image example from http://zetcode.com/db/sqlitepythontutorial/ but with .format() query generation

Is there a way to achieve this with .format()? I want to use a consistent way of inserting data into the db.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can format you BLOB data as a BLOB LITERAL value according to the [SQLite docs](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html), e.g.

```
X'53514C697465'
```

The binary data can be encoded as a hex digit string ahd then be inserted using format.

```
with open(path, 'rb') as f:
    "X'{0}'".format(r.read().encode('hex'))
```

Comment: Note also that the data must not be wrapped with `Binary` for this to work. `binary = open("woman.jpg", "rb").read()` works.

Comment: So the final correct way is: "X'{0}'".format(open(path, "rb").read().encode('hex') Thank you very much, too easy.